# Cut off bottom of element with dynamic height

Tags: html, css

I recently registered for a forum that let's you modify your post layout with a little bit of CSS but the problem is that at the bottom of each post it always adds a few line breaks and a couple of dashes to separate your post's content and your signature. I do not plan on ever using a signature and the only things I put in that section are the two closing tags for the post layout. What I am trying to do it crop the bottom of the inner element so that the line breaks and dashes below each post are hidden. Here's a link to my profile on the forum which contains an example post.

http://jul.rustedlogic.net/profile.php?id=3182

Keep in mind I need for the inner element (`.dialogue`) to always be centered vertically and horizontally. Both it's height and width are dynamic.

EDIT: Having trouble with the height of the background element.

```css
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC";
.background{
  position:relative;
  background:#30619c url(http://example.com/jul/cave-bottom.gif) repeat-x bottom left;
  height:100%;
  padding:60px;
  text-align:center;
}
.background:before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background:url(http://example.com/jul/cave-top.gif) repeat-x top left;
  width:100%;
  height:131px
}
.background:after{
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  vertical-align:middle
}
.dialogue{
  text-align:left;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-smooth:never;
  -webkit-font-smoothing:none;
  border:16px solid transparent;
  border-image:url(http://example.com/jul/yi-border.png);
  border-image-slice:16;
  border-image-repeat:repeat;
  background-color:#286048;
  padding:10px;
  font-family:'Amatic SC',monospace;
  font-size:24px;
  color:#fff;z-index:1
}
.dialogue a{
  color:#fff
}
.dialogue blockquote{
  margin:10px 0;
  padding:10px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  border:none
}
.dialogue blockquote hr{
  visibility:hidden;
  margin:0
}
.dialogue blockquote font:first-child{
  font-family:'Amatic SC',monospace;
  font-size:21px
}
```

```html
<td valign="top" height="220" id="post3182" class="tbl font tdbg1">
  <div class="background">
    <div class="dialogue" style="overflow: hidden;">
      Sample text. 
      <blockquote>
        <font class="fonts">
          <i>Originally posted by fhqwhgads</i>
        </font>
        <hr>
        A sample quote, with a 
        <a href="about:blank">link</a>
        , for testing your layout.
        <hr>
      </blockquote>
      This is how your post will appear.
      <br><br>
      --------------------
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Can you use a wrapper for all your text in a post?

Comment: unfortunately no because the elements are inserted into the post by adding markup in the header and signature sections so it will always have to include those line breaks and dashes from the signature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works at least on FF, Chrome and IE8:

```css
.dialogue {
    line-height: 1.25;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.dialogue:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: -2.5em;
}
```

```css
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC";
.background{
  position:relative;
  background:#30619c url(http://lukelogiudice.com/jul/cave-bottom.gif) repeat-x bottom left;
  height:100%;
  padding:60px;
  text-align:center;
}
.background:before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background:url(http://lukelogiudice.com/jul/cave-top.gif) repeat-x top left;
  width:100%;
  height:131px
}
.background:after{
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  vertical-align:middle
}
.dialogue{
  text-align:left;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-smooth:never;
  -webkit-font-smoothing:none;
  border:16px solid transparent;
  border-image:url(http://lukelogiudice.com/jul/yi-border.png);
  border-image-slice:16;
  border-image-repeat:repeat;
  background-color:#286048;
  padding:10px;
  font-family:'Amatic SC',monospace;
  font-size:24px;
  color:#fff;z-index:1
}
.dialogue a{
  color:#fff
}
.dialogue blockquote{
  margin:10px 0;
  padding:10px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  border:none
}
.dialogue blockquote hr{
  visibility:hidden;
  margin:0
}
.dialogue blockquote font:first-child{
  font-family:'Amatic SC',monospace;
  font-size:21px
}
.dialogue {
    line-height: 1.25;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.dialogue:after{
  content: '';
  display:block;
  margin-bottom: -2.5em;
}
```

```html
<td valign="top" height="220" id="post3182" class="tbl font tdbg1">
  <div class="background">
    <div class="dialogue" style="overflow: hidden;">
      Sample text. 
      <blockquote>
        <font class="fonts">
          <i>Originally posted by fhqwhgads</i>
        </font>
        <hr>
        A sample quote, with a 
        <a href="about:blank">link</a>
        , for testing your layout.
        <hr>
      </blockquote>
      This is how your post will appear.
      <br><br>
      --------------------
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: that works as far as making the dialogue element the right size but the dashes are still visible below I updated it — http://jul.rustedlogic.net/profile.php?id=3182

Comment: @Luke Try it with `overflow:hidden`. I didn't include that at first because the snippet didn't seem to need it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.dialogue {
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 1.25;
}
.dialogue > br:last-child {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: -2.5em;
}
```

```css
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC";
.background{
  position:relative;
  background:#30619c url(http://lukelogiudice.com/jul/cave-bottom.gif) repeat-x bottom left;
  height:100%;
  padding:60px;
  text-align:center;
}
.background:before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background:url(http://lukelogiudice.com/jul/cave-top.gif) repeat-x top left;
  width:100%;
  height:131px
}
.background:after{
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  vertical-align:middle
}
.dialogue{
  text-align:left;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-smooth:never;
  -webkit-font-smoothing:none;
  border:16px solid transparent;
  border-image:url(http://lukelogiudice.com/jul/yi-border.png);
  border-image-slice:16;
  border-image-repeat:repeat;
  background-color:#286048;
  padding:10px;
  font-family:'Amatic SC',monospace;
  font-size:24px;
  color:#fff;z-index:1
}
.dialogue a{
  color:#fff
}
.dialogue blockquote{
  margin:10px 0;
  padding:10px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  border:none
}
.dialogue blockquote hr{
  visibility:hidden;
  margin:0
}
.dialogue blockquote font:first-child{
  font-family:'Amatic SC',monospace;
  font-size:21px
}

.dialogue {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1.25;
}
.dialogue > br:last-child {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -2.5em;
}
```

```html
<td valign="top" height="220" id="post3182" class="tbl font tdbg1">
  <div class="background">
    <div class="dialogue" style="overflow: hidden;">
      Sample text. 
      <blockquote>
        <font class="fonts">
          <i>Originally posted by fhqwhgads</i>
        </font>
        <hr>
        A sample quote, with a 
        <a href="about:blank">link</a>
        , for testing your layout.
        <hr>
      </blockquote>
      This is how your post will appear.
      <br><br>
      --------------------
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to be affecting anything

Comment: Chrome 37 not seeing anything, Firefox 32 it's cropping the bottom of the background element instead?

Comment: @Luke True, it seems Chrome doesn't allow to style `<br>`.